# MQTT RSMB and mosquitto max connection

Tags: mqtt

i had more than 20,000 users in my app,sometimes i must push some msg to all client,like news,i code while(i<100000) to test max connection to mqtt server,and when i=1018,the rsmb was can not connect,and run the same code to connect mosquitto, i=4000+,but it's not support more then 10,000 client,i try so many way ,and not result,plz help.

Answer (score 1):

In mosquitto you're hitting the maximum open file limit imposed by your operating system. If you're running on Linux you'll need to look at the limits.conf man page under the "nofiles" entry as well as "ulimit -n". You can see current limits with "ulimit -a".

I believe rsmb is limited to approximately 1000 clients but you should take notice of its licence which states it is for evaluation only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mosquitto on linux or ubuntu , you might need to use mosquitto.conf to define the number of connection

The maximum number of client connections to allow is as per listener setting.
Default is -1, which means unlimited connections. Note that other process limits mean that unlimited connections  are not really possible. Typically the default maximum number of 
connections possible is around **1024**.

**max_connections -1**

If you want to go past this , you might need to use a scalable message broker . Some of the products like IBM message sight ,say that they offer this scalable .